# Segmentation fault when adding elements to a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a class with a vector of elements and a root element of a graph that defines adjacences between these elements:

```
class Graph
{
     Public:
     Graph::update(const Data& data);
     [...]
     private:
            std::vector<Node> nodeList;
            Node* root;
     [...]
}

Graph::update(const Data& data)
{    
    int n=3;
    std::vector<Node*> newNodes;

    nodeList.push_back(Data(parameters1));
    nodeList.push_back(Data(parameters2));
    nodeList.push_back(Data(parameters3));
    size=nodeList.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        newNodes.push_back(&(nodeList[size-i-1]));
    node->addChildren(newNodes,n);
}
```

The graph structure is recursive:

```
class Node
{
     public:
     [...]
     void addChildren(std::vector<Node*> nodes,int& n);
     [...]
     private:
          std::vector<Node*> children;
          std::vector<Data> data;
          std::vector<Node*> brothers;
     [...]
}
```

Here the problematic method:

```
void Node::addChildren(std::vector<Node*> nodes, int& n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
         children.push_back(nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

The function `addChildren` incurs a segmentation fault even if I try to insert a null pointer or an element created in the function scope. The debugger stops in the "newallocator.h" file, used by the `push_back`.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Also is `n == nodes.size()`?

Comment: why do you pass a `std::vector` together with its size `n` ? This somehow looks like a `vector` trying to imitate a c-style array

Comment: Yes it is not a problem of index out of bounds, the program crashes on the first run of the loop. The vector children is empty in that point.

Comment: Where do the nodes come from?

Comment: n is equal to the size of nodes

Comment: `newNodes.push_back(&(nodeList[size-i-1]));` these addresses are invalidated whenever the vector nodeList has to resize.

Comment: Probably it was a problem of inconsistance of the pointer assigned in the push_back, maybe due to a resizement of the nodeList vector, as manni66 suggested. I solved the problem navigating my list without using pointers but integer indexes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see an error with the function `addChildren`, so I'd assume your problem is in the `node` instance on which the function is called. It is not visible in your code extract whether it was properly created and has not yet been destroyed or moved.

If your `node` pointer is not pointing to an existing object, that would explain the segmentation fault.

Comment: Actually I think it was a problem of inconsistance of the pointer assigned in the push_back, maybe due to a resizement of the nodeList vector. I solved the problem navigating my list without using pointers but integer indexes. Thank you!